# Using group by and count with content provider in android

Tags: java, android, database, android-contentprovider

I want to retrieve list of missed call from call log db in android. But if there is more than one missed call from a number than i want only one record for that number with a column name indicating number of missed call from that particular number. I would also like to fetch other details such as name,phone type extra.
 I have written code which gives all missed call list . For ex if i have two missed call from same number than i get two record.

Below is my code

```
String strSelection=null;
String projection[]={Calls.CACHED_NAME,
   Calls.NUMBER,
   Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
   Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL};

strSelection = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = "
    + android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;

Cursor missedCursor = null;         
missedCursor = mContext.getContentResolver()
   .query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,strSelection, null, 
       Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Please help in improving my code.

Thanks.

Comment: In short: I want to display missed call from a number/contact mentioning the total number of missed user has got from particular number. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've created selection

```
CallLog.Calls._ID + " in (SELECT " + CallLog.Calls._ID + " FROM calls WHERE type != " + CallLog.Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE + " GROUP BY " + CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+")"
```

and it works for me, but NOTE we used hardcoded table name "calls"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Group By param

```
strSelection = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " +        
android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE +") GROUP BY (" + Calls.NUMBER+ ")";
```

Comment: Not working. Exception :

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, number, numbertype, numberlabel FROM logs WHERE (logs.logtype=100 OR logs.logtype=110 OR logs.logtype=900 OR logs.logtype=500 OR logs.logtype=800 OR logs.logtype=120 OR logs.logtype=510 OR logs.logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logs.logtype=300 OR logs.logtype=950) AND ((type = 3 GROUP BY (number)) AND ((type != 4)) AND (logtype=100 OR logtype=500 OR logtype=950)) ORDER BY date DESC